# How do I unselect/unfocus a text field in javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode

I have a mobile web app that I want the textfield to be deselected once the user clicks send because right now when the user clicks send the ios keyboard comes right back up and its hard to tell if the message went through or not.

link to the web app
www.306radio.ca/mobile/chat

Comment: to remove focus from an element you just need to set focus to another element. in your example after clicking send something in your code is setting focus back to the text box - this is why you get the keyboard pop up - publish the code when clicking "send"

Comment: You're doing something wrong.  I've worked with apps that do something very similar to what you describe, and they don't show the ios keyboard in this manner.  Without seeing your code, I don't know how this is answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `blur()` on the textfield to hide the keyboard, or `focus()` on a non-textfield item, such as the submit button.

The problem arises because the focus is returned to the textfield after the user clicks send.

Comment: Thanks, I found out where I did that.